# Random function always returns 1

Tags: c, gcc, random

My random function always returns a "1" rather than... anything
It is supposed to return a "0" or "1"

```
int rnd() {
    unsigned int num0 = rand();
    if(num0 < 32767.5) {return 0;}
    if(num0 > 32767.5) {return 1;}
}

int chk;
bool _True = true;

int main(void) {
    while(_True) {
        chk = rnd();
        printf("%i\n", chk);
        //if(chk == 1) {printf("%i\n", chk); _True = false;}
        //if(chk == 0) {printf("%i\n", chk); _True = false;}
    }
}
```

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong in your code but when I run it, I always get the value of `0` from the `rnd()` function. That's because `RAND_MAX` is defined as 32767 on my system. But why are you comparing an `unsigned int` to a floating-point constant?

Comment: Well, for one you never seeded your rng. Second, it would probably be easier to determine whether "always 1" is presumptive by only printing  when it is *not* 1. And finally, the domain of your `rand()` is highly prejudicial. If you're looking for a random "bit" then just `return rand() & 1;` (or `rand() % 2` also works). Whatever told you to do that floating point comparison didn't do you many favors.

Comment: `_True` Identifiers with leading `_` followed by upper case letter are _reserved_. Do not use them in your code.

Comment: On many systems `RAND_MAX` is a lot bigger than 32767; on mine it is 2147483647.  So your function will occasionally return zero, but with probability only about 1/65536, and if you just eyeball it you may only see 1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, rand() gives a pseudo-random number based on a seed. If you don't call srand() before rand(), you will get the same sequence of random numbers every time you run the program.

Second, the rand() function returns a pseudo-random number in the range of 0 to RAND_MAX.

RAND_MAX is a constant whose default value may vary between implementations but it is guaranteed to be at least 32767.

You seem to be assuming RAND_MAX is twice 32767.5?

I would suggest calling srand() first and then testing versus RAND_MAX / 2, or setting your value to rand() % 2 instead.

(You could have determined such by printing what rand() was returning, and/or by looking up the documentation of rand().)